# how to call method with in the same method in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am not able to call the same method inside the method. Could anyone tell how to do this in Vue js? Here's my code:

```es6
saveTimeSliceConfig (eachConfigObj) {
    console.log(eachConfigObj)
    var x = {
        'y':1234
    }
    this.saveTimeSliceConfig (x) 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? My guess is that `this` is not bound correctly. What is calling the method initially? Also your code would produce an infinite recursion.